# Is my pc competible with Elementary OS?

Tags: system-installation

I have HP 15-db0058nt notebook which has Ryzen 3 2200u with Vega 3 GPU. 12 Gigs of ram installed and has stock 128 GB ssd. Can i use Elementary OS without any issues?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have all informations for minimum system requirements

https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#download-elementary-os

## Recommended System Specifications : From December 2019

- Recent Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor
- 4 GB of system memory (RAM)
- Solid state drive (SSD) with 15 GB of free space
- Internet access
- 1024×768 display

**AMD  Ryzen 3 2200u is compatible with linux 64Bit**, you have all informations here :

https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-3-2200u

I think your **Vega 3 GPU. 12 Gigs** will not have a problem